# Using CxImage in VC++ 2008 MDI application

Tags: image, visual-c++

Im new to cximage so i need help. Im building as MDI project in which i need cximage functionalities.

Please help me by specifying how to load and display an image in the child window.

How to get active windows hwnd and hdc.

this is the requirement:

- Drawing App(Image Viewer and editing) using cximage and Mdi
- First of all, there should be a provision to open an image (any format i.e. tif, jpg, bmp…..).
- The user should be able to do operations like rotate, zoom negate etc. The changes should be saved after prompting.
- The user should be able to draw standard shapes like rectangle, square etc on top of the image.
- Should be able to fill color in the shapes drawn. Save that as well.
- Also user should be given a provision to change an image format(i.e. may be from jpg to tif and so on) and save.

Comment: Atleast refer to some tutorials. i have been google ing for a week.

Comment: the solution should be like the one in the link: http://www.cpp4u.com/files/MTS/visual_C++/VCPP_23.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1300/CxImage itself is a good tutorial and it has sample project as well.

see the tutorial below to which explains how to get active windows handle in MDI app:

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/app_four.html